# Bitcoin for local network

Tags: network, alternatives, local

Is there are any way to use bitcoin or alternative crypto-currency in local network?
I have small home network without internet and have an idea to have a local currency to encourage the children.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set up a local Bitcoin testnet with the Bitcoin-Qt client and some relatively simple configuration. Note that you will need a miner to be processing transactions when the the testnet is in use. More information is available at: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Testnet

Comment: The testnet Bitcoin wiki page references a "Testnet in a box" available here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/bitcoin/files/Bitcoin/testnet-in-a-box/

Answer (score -1):

If you are not tied to bitcoin you could also look at defining your own familly currency with an **Open-Transactions** server (advanced difficulty - https://github.com/FellowTraveler/Open-Transactions/wiki) or with **Ripple** (intermediate difficulty - https://ripple.com)